# The best way to parse XML to data.frame without first lines?

Tags: r

I have this xml:

```
xml <- "
<fixrate_table typ=\"A\">
<table_number>1/A/ABC/2008</table_number>
<date_publication>2008-01-02</date_publication>
<position>
  <currency_name>bat (Tailand)</currency_name>
  <conveter>1</conveter>
  <code>THB</code>
  <average_rate>0,0731</average_rate>
</position>
<position>
  <currency_name>dolar amer</currency_name>
  <conveter>1</conveter>
  <code>USD</code>
  <average_rate>2,4550</average_rate>
</position>
<position>
  <currency_name>dolar au</currency_name>
  <conveter>1</conveter>
  <code>AUD</code>
  <average_rate>2,1629</average_rate>
</position>
</fixrate_table>
"
```

and I want to:
1: get "date_publication"
2: convert it to data.frame where columns are defined as:
colnames(df) <- c("currency_name", "conveter", "code", "average_rate")

```
library(XML)
date_publication <- xmlToList(xmlParse(xml))$date_publication
df <- xmlToDataFrame(xml)
df <- df[-c(1,2), -1]
```

in this solution I'm parsing whole xml 2 times. Any idea to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

For a ton of nodes, that might work best. Although you could use regex, not sure which is really better.

```
library(qdapRegex)
date_publication <- rm_between(xml, 'date_publication>', '</date_publication', extract=TRUE)[[1]]
```

I was going to initially suggest `xml2::xml_find_all`, but that sort of requires parsing it twice.

```
library(xml2)
xmlrd <- read_xml(xml)
xmlnode <- xml2::xml_find_all(xmlrd, "//date_publication")
```